# How does "obey/hypakouo" in Mark 1:27 compare with "obey/hypakouo" in Hebrews 5:9?

Tags: word-study

**Mark 1:27**

> "And they were all amazed, so that they questioned among themselves, saying, "What is this? A new teaching with authority! He commands even the unclean spirits, and they obey him." ESV. [hupakouo/obey].

**Hebrews 5:9**

> "And being made perfect, he became the source of eternal salvation to all who obey him," [hupakouo/obey].

Since unclean spirits are said to obey, and the saved obey, does the meaning of this word change due to context or does it remain constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite uncomplicated - a person object (more on this in a moment) will obey an instruction for one of three reasons:

- because that is what it designed to do and has no choice, eg, Matt 8:27, Mark 4:41, Luke 8:25, 17:6 - the wind and waves obey Jesus' commands
- because the one commanding is far more powerful and one obey out of fear of the consequences, eg, Mark 1:27 - the demonic spirits obeyed Jesus divine commend
- because the one hearing the instruction loves the instructor, eg, Acts 6:7, Rom 10:16, Heb 5:9, 11:8, etc.  It is this kind of obedience that is "saving obedience".

> Rom 6:17 - But thanks be to God that though you were slaves of sin,
> you became **obedient from the heart** to that form of teaching to which
> you were entrusted

This is the difference between the obedience in Mark 1:27 (forced obedience of demonic spirits) and that in Heb 5:9 - saving obedience from the heart.